# Is there a decorator-style syntax that can be used on for-loops in Python 3.6?

Tags: python, syntax, progress-bar, decorator, tqdm

I've found myself modifying iterables very often in Python with `tqdm` for progressbars and was wondering if there was a shortcut for this.  Sometimes my iterables are really long complicated objects so it is tedious to find where the parentheses should be placed.

**Is there a decorator-style syntax to use these types of methods on for-loops?**

For example:

```
# Regular for-loop
data = list("abc")

for element in data:
    print(element)
# a
# b
# c

# Progressbar
for element in tqdm(data):
    print(element)
# 100%|██████████| 3/3 [00:00<00:00, 5300.30it/s]
# a
# b
# c
```

**Is syntax similar to the below possible in `Python 3.6`?**

```
@tqdm_decorator_style_object
for element in data:
    print(element)
# 100%|██████████| 3/3 [00:00<00:00, 5300.30it/s]
# a
# b
# c
```

I know decorators are to modify a function but I was wondering if there is anything similar that can be used for non-function events.  If not, how difficult would it be to introduce this type of functionality in Python?

Comment: No, there isn't. But why not just `it = <long complicated iterable object>`, then just `for x in tqdm(it)`:

Comment: That's what I've been doing but if the decorator option could be done I was going to expand the idea to more things.  Thanks for the suggestion tho!

Comment: I really like the idea.  I think it would be hard.  Maybe prototype what a decorator implementation would look like.  Decorators on functions usually are:
Do some custom stuff.
call the original function.
Do some other custom stuff.

So, they don't really change the function, they just do things on top of functions.  You wouldn't be able to do the same thing for a for loop.  You would have to inspect the code within it and modify it, which is much harder than just wrapping.  Its almost like you want to turn the for keyword into a function/class that can be overwritten.  Hmm not sure.

Answer (score 1):

Decorating a for loop could be considered the same as decorating an iterable's `.__next__()` function.

Because the `.__next__()` function of most (if not all) pre-defined objects is read-only, you have to be really sneaky.

A simple way to get around this is to decorate the `.__next__()` function of a custom class.

```
def timesTwo(f):
    def wrapper(*args,**kwargs):
        return f(*args,**kwargs)*2
    return wrapper

class wrapIter():
    def __init__(self,f):
        self.f = f

    @timesTwo
    def __next__(self):
        return self.f.__next__()

    def __iter__(self):
        self.f = self.f.__iter__()
        return self

data = [1,2,3,4]
for x in wrapIter(data):
    print(x)

Output: 2 4 6 8
```

This might be a little bulky but hopefully you can figure out some good uses for it.